# Why is my jenkins job not able to detect changes?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a webhook setup in my Github repository and with the corresponding triggers set in Jenkins. For some reason, it takes 35 mins on average to detect and automatically run job from that PR multibranch.

The strange thing is, other repos have the exact same setup and there is no delay whatsoever. It literally starts running a job as soon as a PR is raised.

Any thoughts on how to solve this? Are there specific logs I can look out for?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is a throttling limit might be applied by Github API when Jenkins is trying to consume the GH API. To validate this you can check the `Multibranch Pipeline Events` log.

[image]

Check [this](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/troubleshooting-guides/github-webhook-triggering-is-delayed) document as well.